# Why my command is not being recognized as an internal or external command?

Tags: python

[Here is my problem. I am being unable to solve it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShkOi.png)

Comment: Please add your code along with the answer and not as an image since it makes it very difficult for the others to read and understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If pip is not recognized, then pip is not in your windows $PATH variable. This can be edited in system environment variables, where you will want to add the path to pip.

Alternatively, run the setup process for python again, and check the box that adds python and pip to $PATH for you. I believe anything newer than python 3.6 and recent releases of 2.7 both ship with pip.